# How to pick non-eigenvector vector

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to perform some computations on a matrix and the algorithm needs an arbitrary start vector. It is essential that the vector isn't eigenvector of the matrix.

I've stumbled upon two different suggestions: to use a random value vector or to use one of the columns of the permutational matrix obtained from LU decomposition.

I've just verified that for some diagonal matrices the permutational matrix contains eigenvectors. Maybe this is limited to diagonal matrix, hence this idea isn't that bad: I just don't know.

What about the random idea?
What would you do?
Thanks a lot

Comment: If you need this vector in a numerical computation you might want to find one that's not _near_ an eigenvector, in some appropriate sense of "near".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a column of the matrix has a nonzero off-diagonal element, the corresponding standard vector can do, as certainly $$Ae_k=c_k\ne \lambda e_k.$$

If you cannot find such an element, the matrix is diagonal. Take the sum of the standard vectors corresponding to two diagonal elements of distinct values.

$$A(e_{k'}+e_{k''})=\lambda' e_{k'}+\lambda''e_{k''}\ne \lambda(e_{k'}+e_{k''})$$

If you cannot find two such elements, drop it.

---

It is possible that some choices are better than others, like the one that maximizes the angle between the vector and its image, i.e. by minimizing

$$\min_k\frac{|e_k\cdot Ae_k|}{\|Ae_k\|},$$ the ratio of the diagonal elements over the norm of their column, but I have no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Most vectors are not eigenvectors, unless the matrix is a multiple of the identity.
Pick a random $v$, calculate $w=Av$, and check whether the inner product of $v$ and $w$ satisfies $$(w.v)^2=|w|^2||v|^2$$
If they do, keep picking other random $v$, and check that, until you have a good one.

Comment: Interestingly, we are suggesting the same metric (cosine of the angle) to assess "non-Eigenality". You do it on random vectors and myself on the standard basis.